# in Magento 2 how to Open Modal popup with dynamic value for dynamic click button?

Tags: magento2, modal-popup, dynamic

When I click on item "edit link" modal popup is open but when i edit other product it will show previous product data.

Can anyone help to get dynamic popup with dynamic data in per different products?

Please refer screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update the code which you have tried to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize edit.phtml file to achieve it. To customize the item renderer file, you can copy **edit.phtml** file from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml

to your custom theme.

add dynamic id to edit link by using below code:

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem(); ?>

<?php if ($block->isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()): ?>
    <a id="your_id_<?php echo $_item->getItemId(); ?>" class="action action-edit"
       href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getConfigureUrl() ?>"
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit item parameters')) ?>">
        <span>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Edit') ?>
        </span>
   </a>
<?php endif ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        var quote_item_id = "<?php echo $_item->getItemId(); ?>";
        $(document).on('click', '#your_id_' + quote_item_id, function (e) {
            //code to open your modal popup
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now trigger popup modal on click of this id.

I hope it will help you out, let me know in case any doubt.

Comment: I have been struggling for this from last few hours and you solve my problem thanks.
+1.

Comment: Welcome @Mehran!